# How can I use proc tranpose to transform this dataset?

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I am attempting to transform the data set below.

```
   Date        Data1      Data2       Category 
 Dec-2012     59          12          Red
 Dec-2012     31          91          Blue 
 Jun-2014     11          71          Red
 Aug-2015     51          85          Yellow
 Aug-2015     16          66          Blue
```

I want to transpose this data into the following

```
 Date    | RedData1| RedData2 | BlueData1 |BlueData2 |YellowData1 | YellowData2

 Dec-2012 |   59   |     12   |     31    |    91    |            |
 Jun 2014 |  11    |     71   |           |          |            |
 Aug 2015 |        |          |     16    |    66    |     51     |     85
```

How would I do this using proc sql? Or any other piece of SAS code?

Answer (score 0):

The data shape transformation can be achieved using two transpose steps.

- step1 - pivot row-wise to vectorize the `data1` and `data2` values into a single column while maintaining the `date` and `category` associations.
- step2 - pivot the data values by `date` using `category` and `_name_` as identity variables that in turn generate the output column names.

Example:

```
data have;
input Date monyy7. Data1 Data2 Category $;
format date monyy7.;
datalines;
Dec2012     59          12          Red
Dec2012     31          91          Blue 
Jun2014     11          71          Red
Aug2015     51          85          Yellow
Aug2015     16          66          Blue
run;

proc transpose data=have out=step1;
   by date category notsorted;
   var data1 data2;
run;   

proc transpose data=step1 out=want;
   by date;
   id category _name_;
   var col1;
run;
```